# Distributed Cache: Clearing entries on owner loss (Apache Ignite)

Tags: distributed, ignite

I have a number of nodes each owning a subset of a large pool of physical resources. Each node only handles it's own resources but needs to do so based on the state of all resources in the pool. 
A node only updates the state of it's own resources but listens to state changes of all the others. 
When a node dies (process terminated, crash, power loss,...) those physical resources die with it and the other nodes must discard them ASAP.

Now i would do this with a distributed replicated cache (so nodes can read the local replicas for performance), but how to "clear" deceases entries (the owning node can't do it). 
Standard answer seems to be Expiry policy = map entry gets X seconds to live without update, then gone. Problem is, if you are thinking in the 100.000 range of resources and 100 nodes, that is a LOT of updates to send everywhere for NOT changing state. Not to mention the work to update each entry before the timeout and discard these updates in the other nodes.

Any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Subscribe to `EVT_NODE_LEFT` via `IgniteEvents`
- Find related entries via `SqlQuery` or `ScanQuery` and remove them